# The OData request is not supported when getting Outlook MIME Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are able to connect to Graph and Read Emails and folders. However , we also need to have Email's MIME message which needs to be saved in our Application as a proof of Approval and later can be downloaded as .eml file.

We referred to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request-3 for making REST call.

However , the response we get is :

The OData request is not supported.

SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.3.1
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]

API/ Permission added are Mail.ReadWrite with Admin consent and User.Read.

Are there ay more settings needed on the Graph API or any other way to get the MIME message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was resolved .
POST should be made like below

> graphClient.users(userName).messages(msgId).content().buildRequest().get();

while I was making call to

> graphClient.users(userName).mailFolders(folderId).messages(msgId).content().buildRequest().get();